# Object I/O Stream java android

Tags: java, android, object, stream

I want to print an object to a file when my app is onStop and read it at onCreate. When I close the app and reopen it the object is not there. The objects acts ok while navigating trough the app, problem only on restart.

The object is an instance ("tl") of TList class - extends ArrayList

read:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    FileInputStream fis;
    try {
        fis = openFileInput("data_t");

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        tl = (TList)ois.readObject();

        ois.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

write:

```
    @Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = openFileOutput("data_t", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(tl);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to read it onStart()

Comment: After onStop() event if your application is not destroyed and it is visible again the OS will call onRestart and then onStart. This is the recommended place to put your read code.

Comment: Tried with the onStart, also with the onPause for the write. The TList becomes empty - nullPointer